# Is there a way to import GeoJSON into GeoServer using some extension without using PostGIS?

Tags: geoserver, geojson, geoserver-rest-api

Is there a way to import GeoJSON into GeoServer using some extension.
I do not want to import to PostGIS, or intermediately convert to shapefiles because that looses the styles but may be that is separate issue may be with ogr2ogr.

I have installed importer and importer-bdb extension. But still format not recognized error was coming while trying to import via the REST API. Same error was coming while trying to import via importer via web interface of GeoServer.

Is there some other extension which does it?

---

Little background of above process. I have some R-lang scripts which creates GeoJSON (120MB) which I am trying to upload to GeoServer so that I can see results overlaid on Google Maps via WMS/WFS.

Comment: GeoJSON does not have styles so I am not sure what your actual problem is.

Comment: GeoServer isn't a database/datastore, therefore you can't import data into it.

Comment: there is an unsupported geoJSON datastore but it won't set up a style for you.

Comment: You could always convert to a shapefile and import that (no need to set up postgis)

Comment: Yes right now I am converting to shapefiles and loading in geoserver but it looks like a workaround. I was hoping there would be some geoserver extension which can be used to import geojson directly.

Comment: @nmtoken I know geoserver uses a directory to store all the shapefiles and serve it using WMS. Can I serve geojson from a directory using geoserver. I have about 120MB geojson so I have to serve it based on bounding box. So I feel serving it as WMS with a bounding box would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Geoserver don't support GeoJSON files likes store. But you have another option, you can use MongoDB extension to use MongoDB like Database, it's a very good option with this kind of files. Good luck.